# Big "M" Method and Dual Simplex give me the different answer.

Tags: simplex, operations-research, simplex-method

Please help, I have an exam in 2 hours....

And it has 1 iteration only...

I have this problem :

> Maximize : $Z=2x_1+x_2$
>
> Constraints :
>
> $$\begin{aligned} 10x_1+10x_2&\leq 9\\ 10x_1+5x_2&\geq 1\\ x_1, x_2&\geq 0 \end{aligned}$$

With dual simplex, first of all i've changed all constraints like this and add the slack variables:

$$\begin{aligned} 
10x_1+10x_2&\leq 9\\ 
-10x_1-5x_2&\leq -1\\ 
x_1, x_2, &\geq 0 
\end{aligned}$$

Then

$$\begin{aligned} 
10x_1+10x_2+s_1&= 9\\ 
-10x_1-5x_2+s_2&= -1\\ 
x_1, x_2, s_1, s_2 &\geq 0 
\end{aligned}$$

Then, with Dual Simplex (1 iteration only), i got:
$$x_1=\dfrac{1}{10}, \quad Z=\dfrac{1}{5}$$

But, when i use the Big M Method with artificial variable like this:

$$\begin{aligned} 
10x_1+10x_2+s_1&=9\\ 
10x_1+5x_2-s_2+R_1&=1\\ 
x_1, x_2,s_1,s_2,R_1&\geq 0 
\end{aligned}$$

I got (using QM for Windows, there is no doubt)
$$x_1=0.9, \quad Z=1.8$$

I doubt with my answer using Dual Simplex. I've tried twice and still got the same answer. Please help me. I don't care with Big M Method, i just want to know where is my mistake when i'm using Dual Simplex.

Thanks.

Comment: how did you select the pivot row in dual simplex?

Comment: @LinAlg i choose the most negative RHS

Comment: For column, i divide $z$ by pivot row

Comment: Your primal problem is $\max \{ c^Tx : Ax \leq b, x\geq 0\}$, so the dual problem is $\min\{b^Ty : A^T y \geq c, y \geq 0\}$. The problem is the starting tableau: $y=0$ is not dual feasible.

Comment: Is that mean dual simplex doesn't work here? Sorry actually i'm not familiar with those max min notation.

Comment: I indeed think it does not work. Don't you typically start with a minimization problem with nonnegative coefficients?

Comment: For the dual of the primal, then yes.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer.... anyway.